# Find a sequence which uniformly converges f(z), and is of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_i}{w_i-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $f\colon\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, analytic in the closed disk $D=\{z:|z-z_0|\leqslant R\}$.

Is there a way of defining a sequence of the form  $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_i}{w_i-z}$ such that $w_i \in \mathbb{C}$ \ $D$, $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and its partial sums uniformly converge $f(z)$?

***Thoughts:***
I have no idea... except maybe for the riemannian sum of $\displaystyle f(z)=\int_\gamma \frac{1}{w-z}dw$ where $\gamma\colon t\mapsto z_0+Re^{2\pi it}$, but then $w_i\in D$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your idea work. Note that the assumption is that $f$ is analytic on the closed disc $\{ |z - z_0| \le R \}$. This actually means (by a compactness argument) that there is some $R' > R$ such that $f$ is analytic on $\{ |z-z_0| < R' \}$. Then write
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w-z_0| = \rho} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw
$$
where $R < \rho < R'$ and approximate the integral (uniformly) by Riemann sums.

Comment: Thanks, But why such R' exists? The derivative of f (over the boundary of the R-disk) can be just one sided... and then I cannot argue for some R'>R....am I wrong?

Comment: The usual meaning of analytic on a **closed** ser is that every point in the set has an open neighbourhood on which  the function is analytic. If you are using another definition you should say so explicitly. (It's still salvagable in this case: look at dilations $f_r(z) = f(rz)$, do the above for each $f_r$ and make a diagonal argument,)